# Relationships between the Orders of an element in a Cyclic group (multiplicative and additive) Relating to prime numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, cyclic-groups, primitive-roots

Let p be a prime. Then, we know that $U(\mathbb{F}_p) \simeq \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$, where $U(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is the group of units of the field $\mathbb{F}_p$. They both have order $p-1$.

Given an integer $a$ , does it hold that:

$\bar a \in \mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ has order $p-1$ in the multiplicative group $U(\mathbb{F}_p)$

IF AND ONLY IF

$\bar a \in \mathbb{Z}/(p-2)\mathbb{Z}$ has order $p-1$ in the additive group $\mathbb{Z}/(p-1)\mathbb{Z}$ ?

They seem unrelated, but using $ (a,p) = (2, 11)$ and $ (a,p) = (2,17) $,  I found that the two clauses are both true in both cases, so I was wondering if these two clauses have a relationship. What relationship do these two clauses have?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

$\bar{1}$ has additive order $4$ and multiplicative order $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}=U(F_5)$

Comment: Oh! Were the two examples that I tried just a coincidence..?

Comment: @Stone I think so